# Intersecting two iterables lazily in groovy

Tags: groovy, guava

If I have two iterables and I want to create a third iterable by lazily intersecting them. How can this be done in groovy. I can and have done this using guava before. ﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean intersect by "joining the elements together, one at a time", I wrote a package [groovy-stream](https://github.com/timyates/groovy-stream) which can do this lazily:

```
@Grab( 'com.bloidonia:groovy-stream:0.8.1' )
import groovy.stream.*

Iterable a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
Iterable b = [ 4, 5, 6 ]

Stream.from( a )
      .zip( b ) { x, y -> [ x, y ] }
      .each { println it }
```

Which will print:

```
[1, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 6]
```

#### Edit:

You could of course roll your own:

```
Iterable a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
Iterable b = [ 4, 5, 6 ]

Iterable zip = new LazyZipper( a:a, b:b, joiner:{ x, y -> [ x, y ] } )

for( r in zip ) {
    println r
}

class LazyZipper implements Iterable {
    Iterable a
    Iterable b
    Closure  joiner

    class LazyIterator implements Iterator {
        Iterator ia
        Iterator ib

        void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException() }
        boolean hasNext() { ia.hasNext() && ib.hasNext() }
        Object next() { joiner( ia.next(), ib.next() ) }
    }

    Iterator iterator() {
        new LazyIterator( ia:a.iterator(), ib:b.iterator() )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaa I went through your product yesterday. I was exploring something out of the box from groovy 2.x. My last resort is your thingy. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @Amit Added a version that you can roll yourself if you don't want groovy-stream as a dependency. There's nothing lazy that I know of in core groovy